# Gremling console queries to JanusGraph are randomly slow

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I have a super easy gremlin query which I send to a IBM Cloud hosted JanusGraph with gremlin console. Strangely, the execution time is very fast sometimes and then again very slowly. What can that be? The property `uid` is of type string and could be an GUID but also something other.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('uid', 'f287342c-ff84-4102-8f18-f3aa759470a7').hasLabel('product').profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[uid.eq(f287342c-ff84-4102-8f...                     1           1        1107.212   100.00
    \_condition=(uid = f287342c-ff84-4102-8f18-f3aa759470a7 AND ~label = product)
    \_isFitted=false
    \_query=[]
    \_orders=[]
    \_isOrdered=true
  optimization                                                                                 0.014
  optimization                                                                                 0.055
  scan                                                                                         0.000
    \_condition=VERTEX
    \_query=[]
    \_fullscan=true
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -        1107.212        -
gremlin> g.V().has('uid', 'f287342c-ff84-4102-8f18-f3aa759470a7').hasLabel('product').profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[uid.eq(f287342c-ff84-4102-8f...                     1           1         129.861   100.00
    \_condition=(uid = f287342c-ff84-4102-8f18-f3aa759470a7 AND ~label = product)
    \_isFitted=false
    \_query=[]
    \_orders=[]
    \_isOrdered=true
  optimization                                                                                 0.014
  optimization                                                                                 0.056
  scan                                                                                         0.000
    \_condition=VERTEX
    \_query=[]
    \_fullscan=true
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -         129.861        -
gremlin> g.V().has('uid', 'f287342c-ff84-4102-8f18-f3aa759470a7').hasLabel('product').profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[uid.eq(f287342c-ff84-4102-8f...                     1           1        2581.514   100.00
    \_condition=(uid = f287342c-ff84-4102-8f18-f3aa759470a7 AND ~label = product)
    \_isFitted=false
    \_query=[]
    \_orders=[]
    \_isOrdered=true
  optimization                                                                                 0.024
  optimization                                                                                 0.094
  scan                                                                                         0.000
    \_condition=VERTEX
    \_query=[]
    \_fullscan=true
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -        2581.514
```

Comment: Note that the profile output is giving a clue as it shows `fullscan=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by adding an index to property `uid`. I thought, JanusGraph will do this automatically, but that's not how it is. Use follwing steps on the JanusGraph gramlin console.

```
gremlin> graph = ConfiguredGraphFactory.open('g')
gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement()
gremlin> uidKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey('uid')
gremlin> mgmt.buildIndex('uidIndex', Vertex.class).addKey(uidKey ).buildCompositeIndex()
gremlin> mgmt.commit()
```

This is an adaption of the JanusGraph [documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-management/index-performance/#index-uniqueness).